# How to detect if FragmentTransaction is in progress

Tags: android, fragment

my problem is quite simple to explain, but complex to solve.

I have container B which is parent of container A.
I replace fragment in container A.
I remove container A from container B.
I get exception:

```
Caused by:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f060090 for fragment         myappMapFragment{41e52848 #3 id=0x7f060090}
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:865)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:523)
at com.myapp.android.app.app.onStart(app.java:831)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1167)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5216)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2073)
... 11 more
```

So to be more precise, view is removed before transaction is executed. Is there a way to check if transaction is in progress, or the only way is setting flag transactionInProgress=true before commit, and change it to false via callback from fragment?